# how do i align my css drop down menu in center?

Tags: html, css

i tried everything, but can not center my menu in the center, may anybody help me? it is like in the image [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4JPW.jpg) i think the problem is in my css...
 It just stays to the left. Any ideas? Thank you ahead of time.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(2cg3c.jpg);
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .7;
  border: 3px solid #285189;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sweets</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project1.css" </head>

  <body>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2</li>
      <li><a href="#">3</li>
      <li><a href="#">4</li>
      <li><a href="#">5</li>
     
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">7</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">8</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">9</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Low Hanging Fruit answer:

The easiest fix is set the `ul` to be `display: inline-block` and set the containing `div` to be `width: 100%; and text-align: center`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(2cg3c.jpg);
}
.menu-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .7;
  border: 3px solid #285189;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sweets</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project1.css" </head>

  <body>

    <div class="menu-container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2</li>
      <li><a href="#">3</li>
      <li><a href="#">4</li>
      <li><a href="#">5</li>
     
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">7</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">8</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">9</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

When you set an element's display to `inline-block`, that element will have both qualities of an `inline` element and a `block` element.  In other words it is a block element that can act like html text so properties like `text-align: center` will apply to it.

### Additional Answers

There are 3 other ways to center elements, each good for different situations:
http://codepen.io/jzhang300/pen/QdwjMz

1) `display: block` and `margin: auto`
This is good for centering something that has a specified width.

2) `flexbox`
This is the most comprehensive way to layout elements for most cases.  Advantage with this is you can also vertically align elements, not just horizontally.

3) `position: absolute`
This is good for when you want to center elements with dimensions that exceed container dimensions.  It also vertically centers.